# Customer account registered with double opt-in shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I created a new flow builder "Customer account registered with double opt-in" but when the user registers their email address it does not send the verification email to their email address.
On the Event log file, it shows this error:-
debug (100)
{
"source": "core",
"environment": "prod",
"additionalData": []
}

How can I solve this issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2idG.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the actual error log at `var/log/prod-{YYYY}-{MM}-{DD}.log`.

If it's only this particular mail template that can't be send, you should verify that there are no syntax errors in the corresponding twig template and that all used variables are defined, when the mail is going out. If you're unsure if changes were made compare the current template to the [original template created by a database migration](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/9bd0dbf7be832a32e82010801169be2792ad3a40/src/Core/Migration/V6_3/Migration1607500561UpdateSignUpMailTemplateTranslation.php#L67).

For further debugging [see the `MailService` class](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/9bd0dbf7be832a32e82010801169be2792ad3a40/src/Core/Content/Mail/Service/MailService.php) to find if exceptions are being thrown or if the `send` method is even getting called at all.